# Is there a way to process backorder in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

With out-of-stock products, I can add them into the cart but cannot proceed with checkout. Is there a way to send backorders in Opencart? I don't think there are modules available that does this. Anyone know of an easier way to do this?

Comment: What is meant by backorder? If You mean that somebody may order the goods that are out of stock - this is possible by setting in administration.

Comment: Yes you are right. I found it- it's in the `System > Settings`. I thought I saw it before somewhere. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Added that as an answer so that You can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed in the comment:

By setting the option in `System > Settings > Options tab` You should be able to allow ordering the products that are out of stock if this is what You mean by backorder.

Comment: Yes that should do with my current requirement.